# Is it possible to populate external page as dialog in particular div than in whole page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to populate external page as dialog in particular div  than in whole page in jquery mobile. At present there are two divs where in one div menu has been given and another div is having some data. and clicking on any item on the div a dialog will be slided, that is it is external html page so it is sliding the total page and getting in new page, where as i need those dialogs to be display in content div and always the side menu div should be shown. is it possible, if so can someone help me please thanks

Comment: you can use the jquery load() method to load an html page into a div: http://api.jquery.com/load/.  You can also use iframes to embed pages within a page.

Comment: thank you.can you please give some examples?